# Empty ListBox Values

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I have 3 Listboxes. In the properties I have selected the ListStyle as fmListStyleOption and the MultiSelect as fmMultiSelectMulti. Here is the current code:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

Me.lstProperties.RowSource = "FilterData"

Me.lstStmts.RowSource = "ListofProps"

Me.lstLoans.RowSource = "FilterLoans"

End Sub
```

I am using dynamic named ranges in hope that it will only show data in the Listbox for cells that actually have values. Unfortunately it shows a long list of blank lines with checkboxes anyways.

Does anyone know how to make sure that the Listbox only shows data with values i.e. if there are 2 cells in my named range with data then there are only two checkboxes in my listbox.

[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POyaQ.jpg)

Comment: How do you set your dynamic range? It works as expected on my end.

Comment: hmmm... =OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$5,2,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:$N$5),14)

Comment: I now notice that that is picking up more than just used cells.

Comment: I have found the issue. The correct dynamic named range should be : =OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$5,2,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5),14).

Answer (score 0):

An easier why to do this would be to create an array from your range and assign the array to the `Listbox.List` property.  This will allow you to use `SpecialCells` to filter the data.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

    Me.lstProperties.List = getArrayFromRange(Range("FilterData").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    Me.lstStmts.List = getArrayFromRange(Range("ListofProps").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

    Me.lstLoans.RowSource = getArrayFromRange(Range("FilterLoans").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

End Sub

Function getArrayFromRange(rng As Range)
    Dim arr
    Dim a As Range
    Dim count As Long, x As Long, y As Integer

    ReDim arr(1 To rng.CountLarge, 1 To rng.Columns.count)

    For Each a In rng.Areas

        For x = 1 To a.Rows.count

            count = count + 1

            For y = 1 To rng.Columns.count
                arr(count, y) = a.Cells(x, y).Value
            Next

        Next
    Next

    getArrayFromRange = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my dynamic named range was not properly set up. The formula for the named range should have been:

```
=OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$5,2,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5),14)
```

and not:

```
=OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$5,2,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:N$5),14).
```